# When is $|f(x)|$ equivalent to $f(|x|)$

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, absolute-value

Specifically for functions of a complex variable. Are there any rules of thumb?

Answer (score 3):

When the function is nonnegative on the nonnegative real axis, and the magnitude is constant on circles centered at the origin. And only then.

Comment: That is when the magnitude is constant on circles through the origin, or the function only takes one value on circles through the origin? Sorry if this is a silly question

Comment: This does not give all such functions.  Consider, for example, $f(x) = -1$ if $x = -1$, and $f(x) = 1$ elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, magnitude is constant on circles; typing too quickly.

Comment: @AndreNicolas thanks!